# O que são interfaces funcionais?

Tags: java, interface, java-8

O que são interfaces funcionais em Java?

Esse conceito já existia ou surgiu a partir da versão 8 do Java?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As interfaces no Java 8 ganharam muitos recursos novos e poderosos, como métodos abstratos e *default*.

Falando especificamente sobre as **Interfaces Funcionais**, o conceito é de uma Interface que contém apenas um método abstrato, como é o caso de [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), por exemplo. Este tipo de Interface é usado em situações específicas, sendo comum a instanciação é através de uma classe anônima.

## Definição facilitada através de anotação

A partir do Java 8, essas Interfaces podem ser anotadas com `@FunctionalInterface`:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Runnable {
    public abstract void run();
}
```

Ao declarar mais de um método (exceto os métodos já presentes na classe Object), o compilador vai reclamar, evitando erros desnecessários.

## Onde isso é usado?

### Expressões lambda

Com a garantia de que a Interface somente possui um método, este conceito torna-se útil quando combinado, por exemplo, com uma [expressão lambda](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Suponha que temos um método com a assinatura `invoke(Runnable r)`. Antes do Java 8, poderíamos usar um `new Runnable` e sobrescrever o método `run()` da seguinte forma:

```java
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread executando...");
    }
};
invoke(r);
```

Em Java 8, o código equivalente fica muito mais simples:

```java
invoke(() -> System.out.println("Running"));
```

Uma implementação de `Runnable` é criada, cujo conteúdo do único método `run()` é o valor da expressão lambda.

### Referências a métodos

O Java 8 também traz o conceito de [referências a métodos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). Esta é uma ótima forma de reaproveitar código e evitar a criação de classes desnecessárias, principalmente no caso de classes com um método que serve apenas para delegar a execução para outro.

Por exemplo, ao invés de criar um `Comparator` diferente cada vez que precisamos ordenar uma lista ou array, podemos passar apenas uma referência ao método que faz a comparação. Considere a seguinte implementação:

```java
class ComparisonProvider {
    public int compareByName(Person a, Person b) {
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
    }

    public int compareByAge(Person a, Person b) {
        return a.getBirthday().compareTo(b.getBirthday());
    }
}
```

Podemos referenciar um dos métodos para ordenar um array, assim:

```java
ComparisonProvider myComparisonProvider = new ComparisonProvider();
Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, myComparisonProvider::compareByName);
```

Como o segundo parâmetro do método `sort()` recebe um [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Runnable.html), que é uma Interface Funcional, o Java consegue criar uma implementação para ela com o método passado como referência.

## Referências para leitura

- [Tudo sobre o Java 8](http://www.infoq.com/br/news/2013/10/tudo-sobre-java-8?utm_source=infoq&utm_medium=popular_links_homepage)
- [Lambda Expressions and Functional Interfaces](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2191423&seqNum=2)
- [Java 8 : Functional Interface Example](http://java2practice.com/2014/03/16/java-8-functional-interface-example/)
- [Introduction to Functional Interfaces – A concept recreated in Java 8](http://blog.sanaulla.info/2013/03/21/introduction-to-functional-interfaces-a-concept-recreated-in-java-8/)

Answer (score -1):

Há também...
**Interfaces funcionais integradas**

Além das interfaces únicas de método abstrato já mencionadas, o JDK 8 inclui várias novas interfaces funcionais. As mais comuns são Function, Predicate e Consumer, que são definidas no pacote java.util.function. O método map do Stream usa Function como um parâmetro. Da mesma forma, filter usa Predicate e forEach usa Consumer. O pacote também tem outras interfaces funcionais como Supplier, BiConsumer e BiFunction.

É possível usar uma interface funcional integrada como um parâmetro para os nossos próprios métodos. Por exemplo, considere uma classe Device com métodos como checkout e checkin para indicar se um dispositivo está em uso. Quando um usuário solicita um novo dispositivo, o método getFromAvailable retorna um conjunto de dispositivos disponíveis ou cria um novo, caso seja necessário.

É possível implementar uma função para emprestar um dispositivo, da seguinte forma:

```
public void borrowDevice(Consumer<Device> use) {
  Device device = getFromAvailable();

  device.checkout();

  try {
    use.accept(device);      
  } finally {
    device.checkin();
  }
}
```

Aqui você encontra uma excelente fonte de referência...

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/j-java8idioms7/index.html