# Como verificar se uma tabela existe usando jdbc java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Como verificar se uma tabela existe no jdbc usando Sqlite3?

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar os metadados disponíveis:

```
  DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
  ResultSet res = meta.getTables(null, null, "My_Table_Name", 
     new String[] {"TABLE"});
  while (res.next()) {
     System.out.println(
        "   "+res.getString("TABLE_CAT") 
       + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_SCHEM")
       + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_NAME")
       + ", "+res.getString("TABLE_TYPE")
       + ", "+res.getString("REMARKS")); 
  }
```

Veja mais detalhes [aqui](http://www.herongyang.com/jdbc/JDBC-ODBC-Flat-File-List-Tables.html). Observe as advertências em [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Comment: não funcionou! retorna um exception. Eu só preciso saber se a tabela existe no sqlite . Se ela nao existir um vou criar. é uma pequena verificação

Comment: O objeto con é onde você deverá realizar a conexão com o BD SQLite. Você substituiu a "My_Table_Name" pelo nome da tabela que deseja saber se existe?

Answer (score 2):

No meu sistema, usando [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate) do Spring, faço assim:

```
public boolean tabelaExiste(String tableName) {
    HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
    param.put("table_name", tableName);
    return namedJdbcTemplate.query("select 1 from sqlite_master where name = :table_name COLLATE NOCASE and type = 'table'", param, ResultSet::next);
}
```

Explicando:

No SQLite, existe uma tabela principal que guarda todos os seus objetos chamada de `sqlite_master`. Não vi nenhum caso em que você precisasse alterar os dados dessa tabela, mas a consultar eu considero algo plausível, principalmente para verificar se tem algum dado no banco. [Leia mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/171695/64969).

Dentre os campos dessa tabela, 2 pra mim se destacam:

- `type`
- `name`

O campo `type` vai determinar qual o tipo de objeto sendo citado. Pode ser `table`, `view`, `trigger`, `index` etc. O campo `name` é o nome do objeto. Então, se eu quero buscar por uma tabela chamada `MARMOTA`, devo prender o nome do objeto E seu tipo. A consulta ficaria assim:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE
  name = 'marmota' AND type = 'table'
```

Para garantir que o nome recebido como parâmetro posso diferir de caso do nome que está realmente cadastrado o objeto, posso dizer que estou fazendo uma comparação com um `COLLATE NOCASE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE
  name = 'marmota' COLLATE NOCASE AND
  type = 'table'
```

Como simplesmente não me importa o resultado da consulta, apenas se ela retorna algo ou não, eu cito apenas uma constante na parte da projeção dos dados:

```sql
SELECT 1
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE
  name = 'marmota' COLLATE NOCASE AND
  type = 'table'
```

O `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` tem como uma das sobrecargas do método `query` o [`T query(String, Map<String,?>, ResultSetExtractor<T>)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-), que recebe um parâmetro do tipo [`ResultSetExtractor<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html).

Um objeto que atenda à essa interface precisa transformar todo um [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) em um único objeto do tipo `T`. No meu caso, o próprio Java inferiu que o meu tipo é `Boolean`. Para transformar o resultado da consulta em algo que eu possa trabalhar basta verificar se tem resultados no `ResultSet`, então usei a referência de método [`ResultSet::next`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11180/64969) para fazer a transformação `ResultSet -> Boolean`.

---

Se você estiver usando algo mais puro, mais próximo do JDBC, basta extrair o que o `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` automatiza para você. Ficaria algo assim:

```
public boolean tabelaExiste(String tableName) throw SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("select 1 from sqlite_master where name = ? COLLATE NOCASE and type = 'table'")) {
        pstmt.setString(1, tableName);
        try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
            return rs.next();
        }
    }
}
```