# Como listar todas as tabelas de um banco SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

No MySQL, quando rodo o comando `SHOW TABLES` posso ver todas as tabelas presentes em um determinado Banco de dados.

E no caso do SQLite? Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se estiver usando o "interpretador" dele pode usar os comandos `.tables` ou `schema`, para listar as tabelas ou suas estruturas.

Se deseja fazer isto em código e deseja um resultado que possa ser usado para algo na sua aplicação, consulte o dicionário de dados do banco de dados onde tem todas tabelas:

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

O `WHERE` é necessário porque lá também tem os índices. Se desejar só alguns dados, pode filtrar, escolher as colunas, o que quiser, já sabe como usar SQL. Só não vá tentar modificar essa e outras tabelas de controle porque não há gatilhos que processem tudo o que é necessário.

Se testar verá que a estrutura é gravada como texto, ele coloca o comando que foi usado para criar a tabela. Não é muito prático de consultar, mas a informação está lá.

Se fizer um `ATTACH` precisa dizer de qua banco de dados está se referindo. Exemplo:

```
ATTACH novoBanco.db AS novo;

SELECT * FROM novo.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/ListTablesSQLite.sql).

Se precisar das tabelas temporárias precisa consultar outro local: `sqlite_temp_master`.

Isso [está na FAQ oficial](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q7).

Uma coisa que poucos sabem é que todo controle interno dos bancos de dados costumam estar em tabelas normais com um acesso especial *hardcoded*.

Answer (score 2):

Digamos que seu db chama-se MEUDB.

Você pode rodar o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT name FROM meudb.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

Comment: Tem como botar mais de um DB dentro de um arquivo? Achei que o arquivo em si já equivalesse ao DB

Comment: Bem, funciona sim. No meu caso, ao usar `main.sqlite_master` funcionou.

Comment: Sim. No SQLiteStudio ao especificar  meudb.sqlite_master você pode listar,  inclusive,  de bases que não estão abertas.

Answer (score 2):

1. Listar as tabelas do banco:

   `.tables`
2. Mostrar detalhes da tabela:

   `.schema tablename`
3. Mostrar todos os registros da tabela:

   `SELECT * FROM tablename;`
4. Lista de todos os comandos SQLite (terminal/prompt):

   `.help`

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-to-list-the-tables-in-an-sqlite-database-file-that-was-opened-with-attach)

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite3 fffffff.sqlite .tables`