# Expressões Lambda em classes aninhadas com múltiplos métodos

Tags: java, swing, expressões-lambda, java-8

Estava lendo a respeito sobre lambdas e por curiosidade, quis saber porque que não é permitido usar quando a classe/interface possui mais de um método, o que acaba nos obrigando a fazer coisas como abaixo:

```
component.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Pesquisando, achei [essa pergunta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21833537/5524514) sobre a dúvida, mas acabei foi me deparando com uma solução que contorna essa restrição, como pode ser visto [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21851111/5524514):

> ```
> // note the absence of mouseClicked…
> interface ClickedListener extends MouseListener
> {
>     @Override
>     public default void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
>
>     @Override
>     public default void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
>
>     @Override
>     public default void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
>
>     @Override
>     public default void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
> }
> ```
>
> You need to define such a helper interface only once.
>
> Now you can add a listener for click-events on a Component c like
>   this:
>
> ```
> c.addMouseListener((ClickedListener)(e)->System.out.println("Clicked!"));
> ```

Fiz um teste e realmente vi que funciona:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MouseListenerLambdaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new MouseListenerLambdaTest();
        });
    }

    public MouseListenerLambdaTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 120));

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        f.setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        contentPane.add(label);

        contentPane.addMouseListener((MouseListenerHelper) (e) -> label.setText("Clicked"));

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    interface MouseListenerHelper extends MouseListener {

        @Override
        public default void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public default void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public default void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public default void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

    }
}
```

A executar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como foi possível contornar a obrigatoriedade que a interface [`MouseListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) impõe nesse código? Como essa função consegue saber que se trata do método `MouseClicked` se nem implementado ele foi?

> Obs.: eu tenho conhecimento da existência de adapters, e que neste caso poderia simplesmente usar a classe `MouseAdapter`, mas o uso de MouseListener foi apenas ilustrativo, pois nem todos os listeners de java possuem um adapter equivalente.

Comment: Relacionado: [O que são interfaces funcionais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11162/o-que-s%C3%A3o-interfaces-funcionais)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro consideremos o tipo de interface que está a ser utilizada no código exemplificado, uma interface funcional:

**Conceito**

As interfaces funcionais ([Functional Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)) foram introduzidas no Java 8 para dar suporte às expressões lambdas. Estas são diferentes das interfaces normais pois só tem um método abstrato.

**Anotações**

Normalmente levam a anotação `@FunctionalInterface` antes da declaração da interface, embora não seja obrigatório.

**default**

Também foi adicionada a palavra `default` nestas interfaces para que um método da interface possa ter uma implementação e não ser abstrato. Isto ajuda a contornar o problema de poder ter apenas um método abstrato, pois podemos implementar os que não queremos abstratos.

**Nota importante**

Este tipo de interfaces são vitais para uma expressão lambda, pois a lambda só pode ter código para um método, logo para o único método abstrato que está na interface funcional.

> Como foi possível contornar a obrigatoriedade que a interface
>   `MouseListener` impõe nesse código?

No exemplo a interface funcional `MouseListenerHelper` define as implementações para a interface herdada através de default, como no exemplo dado:

```
@Override
public default void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}
```

Deixando vazio e sem código, mas implementado. Por isso implementa 4 métodos da interface menos 1, o que único que faltou e que ficou abstrato:

```
void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
```

Que é exatamente o que é apanhado na lambda pois apenas pode ter um método abstrato, e simultaneamente responde à pergunta:

> Como essa função consegue saber que se trata do método `MouseClicked` se
>   nem implementado ele foi?

Podemos agora reproduzir o mesmo efeito alterando um pouco a interface. Removendo o `mouseEntered` e adicionado o `mouseClicked`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MouseListenerHelper extends MouseListener {

    @Override
    public default void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public default void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }


    @Override
    public default void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    //agora com mouse clicked em vez de mouse entered
    @Override 
    public default void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Agora como o `mouseEntered` é o único método abstrato é o único apanhado pela lambda:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Functional interface??

Comment: Sim, que define apenas um método abstrato, pode consultar [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html). São as que são necessárias para as lambdas, para que estas saibam qual método implementam, pois é so um.

Comment: @diegofm Já editei a resposta, Se estiver confuso é só dizer, que eu tento reorganizar um pouco o texto

Comment: Ótima resposta :)