# Qual é a necessidade de uma interface possuir métodos abstratos?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, interface, método-abstrato

Sabemos que em uma interface os métodos não possuem implementação, apenas assinatura, ou seja, apenas a definição dos seus métodos sem o corpo, concluímos então que todos são já métodos *abstract*, certo? Mas então porque existem declarações como:

```
interface Exemplo {
    void umMetodo();

    abstract void outroMetodo();
}


class ImplementaExemplo implements Exemplo {

    @Override
    public void umMetodo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void outroMetodo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Qual a necessidade de existir um método abstrato em uma interface? Teria relação exclusivamente para criar a possibilidade de interface funcional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Sabemos que em uma interface os métodos não possuem implementação

[Não é verdade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101).

> Qual a necessidade de existir um método abstrato em uma interface?

Nenhuma. Totalmente redundante. Métodos em interfaces são abstratos, a não ser que sejam explicitamente declarados como `default`.

> Teria relação exclusivamente para criar a possibilidade de interface funcional?

A convenção adotada por algumas pessoas é que a uma interface funcional deve ser explicitamente declarado como abstrato, diferenciando de uma interface normal. Mas a única restrição de verdade é que deve ter apenas um método para ser usado em *lambdas*. Tenho a impressão que a convenção começou ser usada por desconhecimento de como o mecanismo funciona já que falam em métodos abstratos.

Comment: Interfaces funcionais deveriam ter o `abstract` na assinatura? Omitir isso então seria uma fuga de convenção tal como nomear classe com letra minúscula?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado dei uma melhorada, tinha misturado as coisas.

Comment: Na primeira colocação acabei esquecendo do Java 8, falha minha, obrigado pelo alerta.

Comment: @Maniero mas ainda estou um pouco confuso em relação a interface funcional, na sua frase da a entender que a interface deve possuir somente um método para ser declaração com uma interface funcional, correto? Então independente se o método é declarado explicitamente como abstrato ou não, uma interface com um único método é uma interface funcional? Obrigado

Comment: Sim, é considerado, apesar não garantir. Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11162/101

Comment: Pois é, muito estranho, no próprio Java tem a classe Consumer ( você pode verificar aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html )  até com a anotação @FunctionalInterface que possui mais de um método.

Comment: Só tem um método abstrato.

Comment: @Emanoel apenas ratificando o que o Maniero falou: `andThen` tem implementação _default_, deixando aberto apenas o `accept`, portanto apenas esse método é abstrato