# Como faço pra passar uma função lambda como parâmetro?

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, java-8

Estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade onde nele tenho que desenvolver uma calculadora com Java. Estou tentando arrumar um jeito de passar funções lambda como parâmetro para que seja possível colocar essas funções dentro de uma lista, assim a calculadora teria varias opções de operações para serem realizadas.

Sei que existem outros meio de executar a mesma ideia usando métodos diferentes, mas eu gostaria de fazer assim. O problema é que eu não sei qual objeto usar para receber o lambda como parâmetro pela função. Escolhi o lambda ao invés de `Runnable` e `Callable` pois além de lambda poder retornar valores, fica mais fácil de um novo desenvolvedor implementar uma nova operação na calculadora, pois ele só precisa adicionar o lambda equivalente a operação e mais algumas informações.

Comment: O ideal seria mostrar a forma como tem neste momento para ser mais facil de perceber as suas dificuldades

Answer (score 1):

Uma função lambda nada mais é do que uma implementação de uma interface funcional. Sabendo disto vamos para a resposta, seguindo as informações que você deu na minha classe principal terei um objeto `List` para conter a lista de funções.

A inferface funcional referente as lamdas ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Lambda<T> {

  T executarFuncao(T num1, T num2);
}
```

A classe que fosse utilizar esta interface (no meu caso a classe Main) ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
public class Main {

    //  Definindo a lista de Lambdas
    private static final List<Lambda> listaLambdas = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //  Criando uma função para soma
        Lambda<Double> somar = (num1, num2) -> num1 + num2;

        //  Criando uma função para subtração
        Lambda<Double> subtrair = (num1, num2) -> num1 - num2;

        //  Adicionando funções a lista de Lambdas
        listaLambdas.add(somar);
        listaLambdas.add(subtrair);

        //  Um exemplo de execução
        listaLambdas.forEach(funcao -> {
            System.out.println(
                    funcao.executarFuncao(1.0, 2.0)
            );
        });

    }
}
```

---

Recomendo como leitura adicional sobre interfaces funcionais e lambdas caso deseje se aprofundar no funcionamento destes recursos:

[O que são interfaces funcionais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11162/o-que-s%c3%a3o-interfaces-funcionais)

[What is use of Functional Interface in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881826/what-is-use-of-functional-interface-in-java-8/36882003)